# scope_identity() and ident_current() conversion to teradata

Tags: teradata, scope-identity

what should be the replacement of **SCOPE_IDENTITY** AND **IDENT_CURRENT** in  **teradata**, below is the SQL code,

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS SlateScenarioId
```

What does this mean and its alternate in **teradata**.

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct replacement, the closest thing is a client option to return the assigned identity values after the insert, e.g.
[Auto-Generated Key Retrieval](https://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/Connectivity/B035-2509%E2%80%90086K/2509ch08.10.05.html)

A common recommendation is to avoid Indentity in Teradata, it's a Warehouse not OLTP...